# Proving through principle of mathematical induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I am just learning about this, so I am a bit rough. I have come to a bit of a problem, and I cannot find out where I went wrong. My original question is:

> $$\text{For every } n \ge 2, \left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{4^2}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) =\frac{n+1}{2n}$$

I went through this process, but I cannot find my mistake:
[image: my process]

[image: my process 2]

Comment: Look at the question again.  It's a product, not a sum.

Comment: Dammit, now I feel like an idiot.

Comment: if I had a nickel for every time I felt that way, I'd be a miilionaire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the steps right, but it is a product.

You did $P(2)$. That working still holds.

We assume $P(k)$ holds:$$\prod_{i=1}^k(1-\frac{1}{i^2})=\frac{k+1}{2k}$$
And use it to show that $P(k+1)$ holds too.

$$\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}(1-\frac{1}{i^2})=(1-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2})\prod_{i=1}^k(1-\frac{1}{i^2})=(1-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2})(\frac{k+1}{2k})=\frac{(k^2+2k)(k+1)}{2k(k+1)^2}$$

Can you reduce this to $\frac{(k+1)+1}{2(k+1)}=\frac{k+2}{2k+2}$?